# Dynamic SQL using mybatis not fetching the mail id

Tags: mybatis, dynamic-sql

I am trying myBatis recently and I have been facing a problem when forming dynamic sqls.

When using myBatis to form dynamic sql like below, it works well with all the fields except when I send value in email field.

No data is fetched when emailId is passed. **I have a doubt if the @ symbol in emailId column is having a problem?**

```
<select id = "getAllWithFilter" parameterType="java.util.Map" resultMap="result">
   SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_LOOKUP

   <where>
      <if test = "firstName != null">
         FIRST_NAME LIKE #{firstName}
      </if>

      <if test = "phoneNo != null">
         AND PHONE LIKE #{phoneNo}
      </if>

      <if test = "emailId != null">
         AND EMAIL LIKE #{emailId}
      </if>

      <if test = "analystGroup != null">
         AND GROUP LIKE #{empGroup}
      </if>

       <choose>
      <when test = "activeFlag != null">
         AND EXPIRATION_DATE IS NULL
      </when> 

      <when test = "inactiveFlag != null">
         AND EXPIRATION_DATE IS NOT NULL
      </when>
   </choose>
   </where>

</select>
```

This is the DEBUG Logs in myBatis - Log4J.

```
DEBUG [http-bio-9081-exec-1] - ==>  Preparing: SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE_LOOKUP WHERE EMAIL LIKE ? AND GROUP LIKE ? AND EXPIRATION_DATE IS NULL 
DEBUG [http-bio-9081-exec-1] - ==> Parameters: abc(String), F(String)
```

Database, contains the following values

```
EMAIL       | GROUP
----------------------
abc@gsf.com | F
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have simply forgotten the `%` surrounding the parameter value:

```
AND EMAIL LIKE '%' + #{emailId} + '%'
```

or

```
AND EMAIL LIKE '%' ||  #{emailId} || '%'
```

depending on DB vendor.

Alternatively, you can add the `%` in the param value after escaping those that might be in the param value.

otherwise it behaves as  =

Comment: my bad.. thanks a lot... when LIKE is used in mybatis, i believed % is inherent :)